# Displaying hidden images in the Pinterest Pin Preview pop-up with addThis plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, pinterest, addthis

I am currently unable to display images on the Pinterest Pin Preview screen that are hidden (with a `display: none`) on my page. On my page where the "Pin It" button sits there is a standard carousel, but I am looking for all images within that carousel to be shown on the Pin Preview pop-up.

I have the script include on my page as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-USERNAMEINHERE"></script>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest left last" title="Pinterest">&nbsp;</a>
```

When investigating into this issue I came across [this post from 2012](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/410885-question-about-your-pinterest-share-button-image-picker), which is essentially the same issue I am experiencing. However there is no follow up to it.

I have experimented with the `image_container` and `image_include` properties of [addthis_config](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1300322-pinterest-image-sharing#.UwyrAYWSl8E), but essentially I can't seem to find a way to show the hidden images.

Has anyone came across this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a reply back from Pinterest Support, as follows:

> Hi, 
>   We do offer similar functionality when using our Pin It button in
>   "Any Image" mode. You can see the code used to generate it by going to
>   our Widget Builder: 
>   http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button
>   However, there's no way for us to automatically include hidden images.
>   The one additional functionality that we do offer is picking up the
>   image stored in the og:image tag on your page, if it exists, so if you
>   populate that tag with one of the hidden images, it would show up
>   first in the list. 
> Hope this helps!
>  Bill | Developer Support Engineer

So it seems that as of May 2014 this is not possible.